# How to use f-strings for formatting large financial numbers

Tags: python, pandas

Okay, I've got a dataframe of data which I've filtered.

Let's not worry about the data - I just want to sum and present that data in a resonable format.

Just so you see the preable code.

```
sum_of_income = data.loc[(data["charity_name"].str.contains("CITIZEN")) \
    & (data["charity_name"].str.contains("ADVICE")) \
    & (data['charity_registration_status']!="Removed")]['latest_income'].sum()

print(f"£{sum_of_income}")
```

I can't work out the f string to convert the value, such as `23499983784.06` tnto something like `£23,499,983,784`

Comment: To specifically answer your question:  `print(f'{sum_of_income:,.0f}')` -> `23,499,983,784`